# How do I create getter and setter overrides?

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

I'd like to encrypt fields similar to this example with mongoose: https://gist.github.com/kljensen/7505729

The code in the above link maps a field to a custom `decrypt()` function for `get` and an `encrypt()` function for `set`.

This causes the plain text value to be encrypted when saved, and decrypted when retrieved.

How would I override getters and setters for a model property in Loopback?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set up setter and getter as follows:

```
<Model>.setter['myProp'] = function(val) {};
```

See an example in LoopBack's [common/models/user.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/6b6ca95e2d8d6bb0f0ddeaa66b14abca83ec47f0/common/models/user.js#L637-L656)

Comment: Thanks Raymond, This gets me working with the setter correctly, but I cannot get the getter to work. I grepped the source and can't find any good examples of that. Is there anything examples for getter you can think of?

Comment: Once I updated loopback to the latest, the `getter` worked as expected by simply returning a string. Thanks for getting me on track!

Comment: @Tom I have fixed the link.

Comment: About example in User model: email setter use 
`this.$email = value` 
instead of 
`this.email = value` 

to avoid name conflicts. 

Here is a special hotfix in the Loopback core for this: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/model-builder.js#L615