# Dynamic Properties or Aggregate Functions in Loopback Models

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

How would I go about using aggregate functions in Loopback models? If I have a model backed by a mysql database, could I have Model1 with a hasMany relation to Model2 (with a given numeric property), and have a property in Model1 that grabs the SUM of that field from Model2?

```
    {
        "Model1" : {
            "Relations" : {
                "model2s" : {
                    "type": "hasMany",
                    "model": "Model2",
                    "foreignKey": "model1Id"
                }
            },
            "Properties" : {
                "total" : {
                    "type": "Number"
                    [SUM of Model2 'amount' field]
                }
            }
        },
        "Model2" : {
            "Relations" : {
                "model1s" : {
                    "type": "belongsTo",
                    "model": "Model1",
                    "foreignKey": "model1Id"
                }
            },
            "Properties" : {
                "amount" : {
                    "type": "Number"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On a separate matter, what is the correct way to put a conditional in a model, so that the value returned by a getter depends on some expression?  I want to return a value from a relation if it exists, otherwise return the one that exists on the primary model.

I have tried this (pseudocode):

```
    module.exports = function(MyModel) {
        MyModel.on('attached', function() {
            var app = MyModel.app;

            MyModel.getter['total'] = function() {
                return (this.model1Id ? this.model1.total : this.total);
            };
        });

    };
```

However, I end up getting a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error (similar to what is noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713445/something-should-be-wrong-with-applying-of-getter-methods-in-model-builder-js)). I'm assuming that is because it recursively calls the getter over and over, but I'm not sure of the way to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK loopback does not support aggregate functions/properties at the moment. Please [open a github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/new) to track this as a feature request.

Note that accessing data of related models is an asynchronous operation, thus it's not possible to reliably implement a property (a getter function) to return the aggregated result.

Here is a mock-up showing how to correctly implementat a computed `total`:

```
MyModel.prototype.getTotal = function(cb) {
  if (!this.model1Id) {
    // No related model, return the total from this model.
    return cb(null, this.total);
  }

  // Fetch the related model and return its total
  this.model1(function(err, model1) {
    if (err)
      cb(err);
    else
      cb(null, model1.total);
  });
}
```

> On a separate matter, what is the correct way to put a conditional in a model, so that the value returned by a getter depends on some expression?
>   I end up getting a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

As I explained in the answer you have linked to, `this.total` calls your custom getter function, which in turns calls `this.total` and so on.

The solution is to read the value from the internal data object:

```
MyModel.getter['total'] = function() {
   return this.__data.total;
};
```

Comment: I can't seem to see anything in `this.__data` — and if I spit out `this` to the console, I don't see a key like that. Am I using it in the wrong scope or something?  I'm doing it in the context that I listed above (simply replacing what I had in the getter function with calls to this.__data as you indicated); is that not correct?

Comment: Note: [it is possible to implement an asynchronous getter function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28860988/2102695) along the lines requested by OP.  Loopback does not support such a function OOTB, however.

Answer (score 13):

This can be done with Loopback's [operational hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks).

```
Model1.observe('loaded', function (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    var sum = 0;

    Model1.app.models.Model2.find({
      where: {
        model1Id: ctx.instance.id
      },
      fields: {
        givenNumericProperty: true
      }
    }, function (err, model2s) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      if (model2s.length) {
        model2s.forEach(function (model2) {
          sum += model2.givenNumericProperty;
        });

        ctx.instance.calculatedProperty = sum;
      }

      return next();
    });

  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea to put it on the 'loaded' hook. I'll have to give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: This also works fine without the aggregation and just add simple dynamic properties. I use it to add a dynamic property that's expose over REST that calculates a recency propery based on a dateModified property.

Comment: I used 'loaded' to add calculated properties as well, but the downside is that you can't filter by these calculated properties.  We have a collection of objects that have a "deletedAt" property  which contains the date the item was deleted.  I added a dynamic property called "deleted" which was true of the "deletedAt" property exists and is not falsy.  Unfortunately I can't filter on the "deleted" property.

Comment: Is there a way to add a dynamic property and use a filter on it?

Comment: yeah, dynamic filter needed huh

Answer (score 3):

You can try 3rd party plugins:

1) Loopback connector for aggregation:
https://github.com/benkroeger/loopback-connector-aggregate

2) Loopback mixins for computed/calculated properties (works only when new model instance created):
https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-ds-calculated-mixin
https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-ds-computed-mixin

3) Loopback mixin for change tracking (launches on every update):
https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-ds-changed-mixin

4) If you need a stats - here is another mixin:
https://github.com/jonathan-casarrubias/loopback-stats-mixin

5) You can count related models:
https://github.com/exromany/loopback-counts-mixin

6) You can automaticly denormalize and save related data and choose what fields will be stored (useful for caching):
https://github.com/jbmarchetti/loopback-denormalize

7) If you need a computed properties for field mapping during import:
https://github.com/jonathan-casarrubias/loopback-import-mixin

Comment: the first one seems to have been taken private

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you ever found what you were looking for, but I was searching for a similar feature and could not find it. After asking stack overflow, [I wound up writing my own plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860988/2102695), which is detailed at that link.

Answer (score 0):

With loopback 3 you can do this:

```
  Report.observe("loaded", (ctx, next) => {  
    ctx.data.SOMEKEY = 'SOME VALUE'
    next();
```

});