# Property setters and getters in Loopback.io

Tags: loopbackjs, setter, getter, strongloop

I would like to know how safe is the usage of **setter** and **getter** properties from model class.

This is already being used in loopback user model and can be seen here: [User Code](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.js#L609)

Why is this not documented anywhere? Can we use it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm still looking for "official" documentation, but our primary engineer documented it in another SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24253273/52160.

If I can find official support in the docs I'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already seen this. I wondered if someone could officially verify it... Anyway, I will keep the question open, until it completely verified..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with some deeper digging, I found that this is actually used and defined in the ModelBuilder class of loopback-datasource-juggler module.
It is defined [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/model-builder.js#L250)

`ModelClass.setter = {};`

And used [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/lib/model-builder.js#L441)

```
Object.defineProperty(ModelClass.prototype, propertyName, {
  get: function() {
    if (ModelClass.getter[propertyName]) {
      return ModelClass.getter[propertyName].call(this); // Try getter first
    } else {
      return this.__data && this.__data[propertyName]; // Try __data
    }
  },
  set: function(value) {
    var DataType = ModelClass.definition.properties[propertyName].type;
    if (Array.isArray(DataType) || DataType === Array) {
      DataType = List;
    } else if (DataType === Date) {
      DataType = DateType;
    } else if (DataType === Boolean) {
      DataType = BooleanType;
    } else if (typeof DataType === 'string') {
      DataType = modelBuilder.resolveType(DataType);
    }

    var persistUndefinedAsNull = ModelClass.definition.settings.persistUndefinedAsNull;
    if (value === undefined && persistUndefinedAsNull) {
      value = null;
    }

    if (ModelClass.setter[propertyName]) {
      ModelClass.setter[propertyName].call(this, value); // Try setter first
    } else {
      this.__data = this.__data || {};
      if (value === null || value === undefined) {
        this.__data[propertyName] = value;
      } else {
        if (DataType === List) {
          this.__data[propertyName] = DataType(value, properties[propertyName].type, this.__data);
        } else {
          // Assume the type constructor handles Constructor() call
          // If not, we should call new DataType(value).valueOf();
          this.__data[propertyName] = (value instanceof DataType) ? value : DataType(value);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
});
```

So it is probably implemented, but not documented...