# How to subtract time -7 hours on node.js / loopback.io

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback 3 to create API, I have model like this

**Section.js**

[image]

**Section.json**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

I want to subtract start_date to -7 hours so that it becomes like this

```
...
"start_date": "2019-06-23T17:00:00.000Z",
...
```

I try using getter from this thread [How do I create getter and setter overrides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223329/how-do-i-create-getter-and-setter-overrides/24253273#24253273) like this

[image]

but nothing has changed, did I implement it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Now you have to call the `Section.setup()` at the end. This is the default `User` model.

So basically,

```
module.exports = function(User) {


  User.setup = function() {
    // We need to call the base class's setup method
    User.base.setup.call(this);
    var UserModel = this;
    UserModel.setter.email = function(value) {
      if (!UserModel.settings.caseSensitiveEmail) {
        this.$email = value.toLowerCase();
      } else {
        this.$email = value;
      }
    };

    return UserModel;
  };

  /*!
   * Setup the base user.
   */

  User.setup();
};
```

I don't know properly how to do that, but I made one MCVE that seemed to work(with bugs):

```
module.exports = function(Some) {
    Some.setup = function() {
        Some.base.setup.call(this);
        var UserModel = this;
        Some.getter.name = function(){
            console.log(this.$name);
            return this.$name+"lol";
        }
    }
    Some.setup();
};
```

Comment: Great, now start_date is change but always show `null`. I try to print `value` in function with `console.log(value);` but I get `undefined`.

Why value return undefined?

Comment: Because `getter` doesn't need arguments, setter needs them.

Comment: If getter doesn't need arguments, how to get start_date value and subtract them? Can you give me example?

Comment: Edited the answer.